# No Runnable Method Junit

Tags: java, junit

I looked at other questions regarding this and it seems the usual answer is a missing "@Test" tag on my method, however I have that, below is an example.

```
package com.company.project.component;

import org.junit.Test;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class SampleTest extends BaseUnitTest {
    @Test
    public void sampleTest() {
        assertEquals(1, 1);
    }
}
```

This results in No Runnable methods

Comment: What is the import of Test? It can be TestNG

Comment: import com.company.project.component.BaseUnitTest;
import org.junit.Test;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

I have another unit test that looks exactly the same, but doesn't have this issue

Comment: You can add an answer with the solution

Answer (score 1):

This code runs well:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import org.junit.Test;


public class SampleTest {
   @Test
   public void sampleTest() {
      assertEquals(1, 1);   
   }    
}
```

This problem might be your BaseUnitTest class or in your project.

Does it has junit library imported?

Comment: I'm using BaseUnitTest in other test classes and it's working

Comment: Try to take off this extends and see if it works! If it works fine, post the BaseUnitTest classe code, so we can try to help.

Comment: I removed it and it still fails

Comment: Please post all code, include the imports. So, then, we might help.

Comment: I've posted it now, I updated to remove the base unit test and it still fails

Comment: It seems to be working now... I just added a @ignore to my class and did a maven clean install, then it started working...

Something must have been messed up with my dependencies

Answer (score 1):

For future references, 
Make sure you are importing the correct JUnit's [Test](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/Test.html) class

```
 import org.junit.Test;
```

There are different frameworks as TestNG with same annotation so problem can happen if you try to run TestNG test(s) with JUnit test framework (or vice versa).

Comment: I figured it out, my environment was just messed up, I'll just delete this question I guess, because it wasn't any specific problem